# OpenGL with GLFW and GLEW - compiling with gcc on windows

Tags: c++, gcc, opengl-3

I'm trying to run an OpenGL program that uses GLFW and GLEW libraries I built myself. The starter code I use is

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>


// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3" << std::endl;
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", 0, 0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }    

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Check if any events have been activated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Render
        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Swap the screen buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    std::cout << key << std::endl;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

Then I type

```
g++ -I<path to headers> Tma.cpp -L<path to libraries> -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -lglew32
```

Which yields a number of 'undefined reference to' errors.

The code should be OK, as I previously run it successfully in Visual Studio.

Comment: Please post what functions linker cannot find. Have you done any modifications to GLFW/GLEW? Where are they (I'm asking about `.lib` files, not headers)?

Comment: If they start with `_imp`, it means, that they are marked as exported. You have defined `GLEW_STATIC`, but have compiled it as static? Why did you even bother with manual builds? First, try to remove `#define GLEW_STATIC` line.

Comment: Sorry for the first comment - I haven't finished it yet. Every one starts with __imp_. Then glGetString, glGetInteger, CreateDCW, GetDeviceCaps, DeleteDC, GetDeviceGammaRanp, SetDeviceGammaRamp, CreateDIBSection, CreateBitmap, DeleteObject, wglGetProcAddress, DescribePixelFormat, SetPixelFormat, wglCreateContext, wglShareLists, wglDeleteContext, wglMakeCurrent, SwapBuffers, wgl_GetCurrentDC. I made no modification to the source of the libraries. The libraries are located in the lib folder, which is parallel to the source folder.

Comment: But you didn't link them. g++ is not VC. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command:

`g++ -I<path to headers> Tma.cpp -L<path to libraries> -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -lglew32`

will not be enough in Windows. You will need to link additional system libraries. For example, every project in Visual Studio 2012 have these attached by default:

```
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib
```

That is why it compiled fine in VS.

`kernel32.lib` and `user32.lib` should be always linked. `gdi32.lib` is required, when you do any graphic operations.

**First solution:**

Link these libraries manually:

`g++ -I<path to headers> Tma.cpp -L<path to libraries> -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lws2_32`

If I remember correctly, `ws2_32.a` is the name of WinSock2 library supplied with MinGW.

**Second solution:**

If you use MinGW, you can use `-mwindows` flag:

`g++ -I<path to headers> Tma.cpp -L<path to libraries> -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -lglew32 -mwindows`

This will link, among few others, `gdi32.a`, `kernel32.a`, `user32.a` and `ws2_32.a`.